# MS word vba - find text and associated headings

Tags: vba, ms-word

Here is some working code in case anyone needs it.
The key word is found using the range.find function, once found the absolute line number is found. Then the selection function scrolls up line by line to find heading levels 1 and 2. The results are stored in array and pasted onto an excel spreadsheet once complete.

If anyone has a more elegant method please let me know.

```
'===================================================
'FIND KEY WORD AND ASSOCIATED LEVEL 1 AND 2 HEADINGS
'===================================================

Sub FIND_HDNG_2()

Dim SENTENCE As String
Dim hdng1name As String, hdng1No As String, hdng2name As String, hdng2No As String
Dim aRange As Range, Style_Range As Range
Dim CurPage As Integer, CurPage2 As Integer, CurPage3 As Integer
Dim hdng_STYLE As String
Dim LineNo As Integer, Hdng_LineNo As Integer
Dim SELECTION_PG_NO As Integer, RANGE_PG_NO As Integer
Dim HDNG_TXT As String
Dim ARRY(200, 5) As String
Dim COUNT As Integer
Dim HDNG1_FLAG As Boolean, HDNG2_FLAG As Boolean
Dim LINESUP As Integer

On Error Resume Next

COUNT = 1
Set aRange = ActiveDocument.Range
Do
    aRange.Find.Text = "must" ' the KEY WORD I am looking for
    aRange.Find.Execute Forward:=True
    If aRange.Find.Found Then
        'extract sentence
        LineNo = GetAbsoluteLineNum(aRange)
        RANGE_PG_NO = aRange.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
        aRange.Expand Unit:=wdSentence
        aRange.Copy
        SENTENCE = aRange.Text
        aRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

        'find heading name and number
        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToLine, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, COUNT:=LineNo        'go to line no of the range
        LINESUP = 0
        Do
            LINESUP = LINESUP + 1
            Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, COUNT:=1
            Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
            Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
            HDNG_TXT = Selection.Text

            'reached first page without finding heading
            SELECTION_PG_NO = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
            If SELECTION_PG_NO = 1 Then     'exit if on first page
                hdng2No = "BLANK"
                hdng2name = "BLANK"
                Exit Do
            End If

            hdng_STYLE = Selection.STYLE
             If hdng_STYLE = "Heading 1,Heading GHS" And HDNG1_FLAG = False Then
                hdng1No = Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString
                hdng1name = Selection.Sentences(1)
                HDNG1_FLAG = True
                Exit Do
            End If

            If hdng_STYLE = "Heading 2" And HDNG2_FLAG = False Then
                hdng2No = Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString
                hdng2name = Selection.Sentences(1)
                HDNG2_FLAG = True
            End If
        Loop

    End If

    HDNG1_FLAG = False
    HDNG2_FLAG = False
    ARRY(COUNT, 1) = hdng1No
    ARRY(COUNT, 2) = hdng1name
    ARRY(COUNT, 3) = hdng2No
    ARRY(COUNT, 4) = hdng2name
    ARRY(COUNT, 5) = SENTENCE
    COUNT = COUNT + 1
Loop While aRange.Find.Found

Call PASTE_RESULT_EXCEL(ARRY)
End Sub

'===================================================
'PASTE RESULTS TO EXCEL
'===================================================

Sub PASTE_RESULT_EXCEL(ByRef ARY() As String)

Dim appExcel As Object
Dim wb As Object
Dim ws As Object
Dim min As String
Dim filename As String
Dim X As Integer, Y As Integer

filename = "DOC_NAME"

Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With appExcel
    .Visible = True
    Set wb = .Workbooks.Add
    min = CStr(Minute(Now()))
    wb.SaveAs "D:\IPL\" + filename + "--" + min + ".xlsx"

    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    For X = 1 To 200
        For Y = 1 To 5
            ws.Cells(X + 5, Y).Value2 = ARY(X, Y)
        Next Y
    Next X

    Set ws = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set appExcel = Nothing

End With

End Sub

'===================================================
'FIND ABSOLUTE LINE NUMBER OF KEY WORD
'===================================================

Function GetAbsoluteLineNum(r As Range) As Integer
    Dim i1 As Integer, i2 As Integer, COUNTER As Integer, rTemp As Range

    r.Select
    Do
        i1 = Selection.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)
        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToLine, Which:=wdGoToPrevious, COUNT:=1, Name:=""

        COUNTER = COUNTER + 1
        i2 = Selection.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)
    Loop Until i1 = i2

    r.Select
    GetAbsoluteLineNum = COUNTER
End Function
```

Comment: Can you use `aRange.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)` instead of a `Selection...` ?

Comment: Thanks Branislav, it seems to be working! I thought it would be something simple....